# Marriv before/after lighting the Menorah

Tags: tefilla, chanuka, zemanim, maariv, lighting

Does one need to Daven Marriv before lighting the Chanukah Menorah or can you light before davening? Why?

Comment: I think it depends when you light. Do you light at sunset or nightfall?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Mishnah Berurah (672:1, and in Beur Halachah ibid. ד"ה לא מאחרים) says that it depends:

- If you usually daven Maariv before nightfall, then prepare the menorah ahead of time, and light immediately after Maariv (so you don't miss the proper time for lighting).
- If you usually daven it after nightfall, then it's better to light first and then daven.
- In the latter case, if you didn't have the chance to light before nightfall, then daven Maariv first (since it is a more usual mitzvah, so the rule of תדיר ושאינו תדיר applies; plus it includes the Biblical mitzvah of reciting Shema), and then light.

Comment: This is all true only according to those who, following Rabeinu Tam, light after nightfall.

Answer (score 1):

I think heard HaRab Mansour say in today's Daily Halacha that you have al mi limsmoch to light candles before arbit.

I don't why yet though.

EDIT: I think I know why NOT- Tadir Kodem.